# Select greater than with expression query

Tags: mysql, zend-framework, zend-framework2

I'm trying to write the following query:

```
SELECT * FROM program
    WHERE (SELECT MAX(surface) FROM lot 
           WHERE lot.id_program=program.id) > $min_surface;
```

The following code works:

```
$min_surface=40;
$select->where('(SELECT MAX(surface) FROM lot WHERE lot.id_program=program.id) > '.$min_surface);
```

However, I would like to use the greaterThan predicate:

```
$select->where->greaterThan(
     '(SELECT MAX(surface) FROM lot WHERE lot.id_program=program.id)'
     ,$min_surface
);
```

The following error gets thrown:

```
Statement could not be executed (42000 - 1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax;   
     check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version 
     for the right syntax to use near 
'`SELECT` `MAX``(``surface``)` `FROM` `lot` `WHERE` `lot`.`id_program``=``program' at line 1)
```

Comment: where is ORDER BY `id` DESC in your query ?

Comment: They is a `$select->order('id DESC');` at the end of my code (not in that sample because it is not causing the error

Comment: its totally different your error code after your edit. can you show the exact error code? and is it like that with those backticks ?

Comment: Yes the backtick are included, which is a bit weird. The error code that is shown is the one that is included in the post. Before, I used `new Expression('SELECT MAX(surface) FROM lot WHERE lot.id_program=program.id')` which was incorrect

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is really no need to use subquery in your case. You can just `join` tables.

```
SELECT program.*, MAX(surface) as max_surface 
FROM program
JOIN lot ON lot.id_program = program.id
GROUP BY program.id
HAVING max_surface > $min_surface
```

This query can be written

```
$select->from('program')
    ->join(
        'lot', 
        'lot.id_program = program.id', 
        array('max_surface' => new Zend_Db_Expr('MAX(surface)'))
    )
    ->group('program.id')
    ->having('max_surface > ?', $min_surface)
```

Hope it helps